# Where do I find online bookshelves with ebooks or PDFs written in Esperanto?

Tags: literature, books, resources

Since Esperanto has existed since 1887, there should be some ebooks (e.g. original texts or early translations), maybe also some later works that were made available for private use by the author/translator, available for (free) download.

Where do I find such online bookshelves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a whole lot of PDF e-books here: http://i-espero.info/files/elibroj/

They include *La Mirinda Sorĉisto de Oz* and others in the series, *Alicio en Mirlando* and *Trans la Spegulo*, as well as the older version of the story (*La Aventuroj de Alico sub la Tero*), *Kristnaska Kanto* and *La Batalo de l' Vivo*, and many others. They seem to be primarily translations, but there may be some originals (I haven't opened every one to verify). However, they are done by an assortment of translators, and the translations vary in quality from excellent in grammar and style, to ones that contain quite a few grammatical errors and are mediocre in style.

Also, the page consists entirely of PDF links (title and author being indicated in the file name) marked with their file size, so no info on the nature of the book, the identity of the translator, whether it's translated or original, etc. So you have to open the file to get any additional information.

Answer (score 10):

http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/eo

You can find quite a lot of books on Project Gutenberg.

And on this page: http://esperanto.us/

Answer (score 8):

There's an [almost complete collection](http://esperanto.org.uk/eldonoj/piron/) of the works of Claude Piron in epub format (amongst others). I recommend all of the books in the *ĉu*-series for a bit of light reading and to learn some new vocab. They are written in a nice style with gripping stories but still easy to understand.

Answer (score 7):

At [i-espero.info](http://i-espero.info/elsutaro/esperantaj-libroj#books) there are more than 150 books available as PDFs. Both translations and original Esperanto literature. There is also an option to download all the books at once as a 250 MB zip file.

Comment: Bother. Ninja'd again! :-P

Answer (score 4):

There is a public group you can join on Facebook called *PDF-a Librejo*.

There are hundreds of free PDFs located in the files section of the group containing many different documents and books in Esperanto.

Here's the link to the group's page: https://m.facebook.com/groups/229120067203802

Answer (score 4):

Ĉe [SmashWords.com](https://www.smashwords.com) oni eblas elŝuti kaj aĉeti kelkajn librojn, por ekzemple [Cent Jaroj da Soleco](https://eo.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_jaroj_da_soleco).

Comment: Ne ĉiuj libroj estas senpagaj sed almenaŭ sen DRM, do private uzebla. The books are not all charge-free, but at least free of DRM.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the late [Don Harlow's Library](http://literaturo.org/HARLOW-Don/), but unfortunately the content and links decayed a lot since his demise. But it still has some good stuff.

Comment: This is where I read La Verda Koro, for example. 

Answer (score 0):

Try this site:
https://eduinf.waw.pl/esp/lern/librejo/index.php
There are many books in PDF, HTML, EPUB and AZW3 formats